# Strange behaviour while using Field lookup in Django

Tags: python, django

I noticed a strange behavior in `in` Field lookup while trying up *[challenge yourself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Home_page)* section of [MDN Django Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org).

I wanted to modify `view.py` to generate counts for *genres* and *books* that contain a particular word (case insensitive), and pass the results to *context*.  I tried to achieve this by following code:

```
# Filtering the word 'comedy' from 'genre' attribute(ManytoManyField) present in 'Book' class

num_word_in_geners = Book.objects.filter(genre__in='comdey').count()
```

Surprisingly, this throws a `ValueError`

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'c'
```

So, I did a workaround by replacing 'comedy' with `inner_qs`:

```
inner_qs = Genre.objects.filter(name__icontains='comedy')
num_word_in_genres = Book.objects.filter(genre__in=inner_qs).count()
```

Now more surprisingly, **this works!** But why? I suspect there is something I don't understand behind [these words](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) in Django docs:

> *In a given iterable; often a list, tuple, or queryset. It’s not a common use case, but strings (being iterables) are accepted.*

Help me clear this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `__in`, you can simply query by:

```
num_word_in_geners = Book.objects.filter(genre__name__icontains='comdey').count()
```

Here I am querying directly in `Genre` model's name field through ForeignKey relationship between `Book` and `Genre`.

Comment: This is sleek! But I still don't understand how this ForeignKey relationship works. Maybe I'm not clear with the concept of ForeignKey itself.

Comment: then you should print the query to see what sql is being generated underneath. Try `print(Book.objects.filter(genre__name__icontains='comdey').query)`

Answer (score 2):

`in` lookup expects iterable, for example `list`. You provided only string, which causes your problem.

To quick fix that, you should simply:

`num_word_in_geners = Book.objects.filter(genre__in=['comedy']).count()`

Comment: Isn't string an iterable?

Comment: Also using ```genre__in=['comedy']``` still throws ValueError

Comment: Well, you can iterate over string, but I don't think you want to iterate over the letters.